# AWS ServerLess Web App Example

Tags: javascript, java, web-services, amazon-web-services, lambda

I was looking into AWS services for a serverless web app development.i was able to host a static webpage in S3.
But I can't find any sample projects with java as lambda functions. I don't have experience with web services and I am confused in the following scenarios

1) Creating a lambda java web API which takes some parameters and generates some results
2) How to call a lambda web API from HTML using javascript, passing some form data as parameters
3) Accessing the output from the web API within the HTML and showing it as a content in the web page

I really appreciate some basic sample codes for the above requirements, i tried a lot online for solutions but can't find any understandable one.

Thank you

Comment: This is not the place to look for "sample code"

Comment: Sorry for the trouble, I tried online a lot. It would be really grateful if you could point out some guides or tutorials for my problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hi think you are at wrong place, this is not place to find sample code. Yet I will refer you few code links.

> 1. Creating a lambda java web API which takes some parameters and generates some results

https://github.com/serverless/examples/tree/master/aws-java-simple-http-endpoint

> 2) How to call a lambda web API from HTML using javascript, passing
>   some form data as parameters & 3) Accessing the output from the web
>   API within the HTML and showing it as a content in the web page

https://api.jquery.com/jQuery.post/

In my opinion, you should not go through this code and develop straight up your app. You first should clear few basic workflow of Client Server and how website works, also try to sharpen your documentation reading skill.

Go Through every technolog's document such as in your case serverless, javascript, html. You will find plenty of getting started code and in detail understanding, which will help you build your product better.

Comment: thanks for your opinion, I will go through as you told